# Reuse iter variable for conditional Skip, Filter, etc

Tags: rust

I have an iterator to which I want to conditionally apply filters, skips, etc. before ultimately calling `collect()`.

In a different language, I might write something like

```
// (Rust-like pseudocode)
let mut iter = [1,2,3,4].iter();
if should_filter {
    iter = iter.filter(|x| x % 2 == 0);
}
if should_truncate {
    iter = iter.take(2);
}
iter.collect()
```

But since `iter` is of type `Iter`, and `skip()`, `filter()` return types `Skip`, `Filter`, I've been unable to reuse the original binding for `iter`. As a result, my Rust code currently looks something like this:

```rust
let iter = [1,2,3,4].iter();

// conditionally filter
if should_filter {
    let iter = iter.filter(|x| x % 2 == 0);

    // conditionally "truncate"
    if should_truncate {
        let iter = iter.take(2);
        return iter.collect();
    }

    return iter.collect();
}

// conditionally "truncate"
if should_truncate {
    let iter = iter.take(2);
    return iter.collect();
}

iter.collect()
```

Is there any way I can avoid this duplication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest solution, and probably closest to what your "other language" would do under the hood, is to box the iterator:

```
let mut iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &i32>> = Box::new ([1, 2, 3, 4].iter());
if should_filter {
    iter = Box::new (iter.filter(|x| *x % 2 == 0));
}
if should_truncate {
    iter = Box::new (iter.take(2));
}
let v: Vec<_> = iter.collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a3f21f9834102a571f3e94a75ba1afda)

Answer (score 8):

You can reliably trust the compiler the optimize loop invariants in this case. Since `should_filter` can not change while iterating, the compiler will figure out that it can check that precondition before the loop and skip the test if `should_filter` is `true`. This means you can simply put the condition into the loop - which seems inefficient - and have much cleaner code. Even if the check does not get removed from the loop body, the CPU's branch predictor will easily skip around it. Similarly you can "inline" the `should_truncate` condition:

```
fn do_stuff(
    inp: impl IntoIterator<Item = u32>,
    should_filter: bool,
    should_truncate: bool,
) -> Vec<u32> {
    inp.into_iter()
        .filter(|x| should_filter && x % 2 == 0)
        .take(if should_truncate { 2 } else { usize::MAX })
        .collect()
}
```

Comment: I accepted Jmb's answer despite the perf hit because it generalized better to my messier, real use case, but I definitely hadn't considered something like this, relying on the compiler (or even the CPU's branch predictions!); thanks for the clever answer and insight